# What are the options available to store variables and functions as separate cases in python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a mathematical model in python, the model has ~20 input parameters that i'm storing in a separate file. I Have multiple cases that I would like to evaluate/modify.

Each case is a ".py" file that holds variables and a few simple functions. What is the bast way to import them into my main Code?

So far i've been using "from CaseName import *" to import all the variables and functions from the case. However this does not lend itself to allowing for looping over the cases.

I've looked at using importlib but some sections of my code require that the imported variables are global. Are there any other alternatives?

Here is a simplified example.

### Case1.py:

```
CaseName = "Case1"
a = 1.0
b = 1.0

def InitialConditions(x):
    return(10*x)
```

### Case2.py:

```
CaseName = "Case1"
a = 2.0
b = 2.0

def InitialConditions(x):
    return(4*x**2)
```

### MainCode.py:

```
from Case1 import *

RunCalculation(a,b)
etc....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html):

```
class Case1(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
        self.x = x

    def initial_condition(self):
        print(10 * self.x)  

# Initialize and use
case = Case1(x=3)
case.initial_condition()

# Rinse and repeat for all needed classes
```

If you start littering your environment with globals, it's probably an indication you should be using a class. If any of your models share a significant number of attributes (input parameters) or methods (functions) then look into extending your classes with [inheritance](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-inheritance-in-python-3).

For instance, if your `RunCalculation` function is always the same, it might be more efficient to create a parent class that contains it as a method and then inherit from that to make your individual cases, like so:

```
class ParentCase(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, x):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.x = x

    def run_calculation(self):
        print(self.a + self.b + 35)

class Case1(ParentCase):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1
        self.x = x

    def initial_condition(self):
        print(10 * self.x)

case = Case1(x=3)
case.run_calculation() #inherited method
```

Comment: This is a very interesting option. Do you suggest that I then make the class a single global in my code as opposed to a set of globals? Or should I be avoiding the globals altogether and pass the class object between functions?

Comment: Avoid globals. You can either pass the class object around or use methods. If your `RunCalculation` function is always the same I would suggest creating a parent class and using it to create child classes (e.g., the edit in my answer)

Comment: @J.Armstrong in your case, a great reason to avoid globals is that you're naming everything `a`, `b`, etc. It's going to be hard to catch bugs if you're using the wrong `a` on accident. Instead, `case.a` is utterly unambiguous

Comment: I've implemented a class based solution as you have described and it is so much more flexible and with the inheritance there is virtually no duplication of work. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @J.Armstrong Excellent! I'm so glad to hear you got a good solution working.  If you feel my post suitably *answered* your question, you can accept it ([more info here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)).